# can any property of the natural numbers be proven by induction?

Tags: set-theory

1-if the set of natural numbers is constructed as in ZF system, is any proved property of N can also be proved using induction?
in other words, does the induction principle have 'limitation' in the sense that
there are some properties of N which can not be proven with it?

2- Does having 'limitation' on the induction principle depends on the system in which the set N is constructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem
2. It depends. For any “natural” definition, one can show an isomorphism in ZF(C). However, there are also nonstandard models of natural numbers (satisfying the Peano axioms) which are non-isomorphic in ZF(C).

Comment: It's not obvious that @Hassan would consider Goodstein's theorem something that is a "proved property of $\Bbb N$."  That depends on whether the proof has to occur within ZFC.

Comment: Well. what if not a proof in ZF(C) could somebody consider as a proof of a "proved property of $\mathbb N$" which is not proved by induction (that is, by Peaono axioms)?

Comment: @MartinVäth I think Robert's point was that Goodstein **is** provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ - it's not provable in $\mathsf{PA}$, but that's a vastly weaker system.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: The fact that Goodstein's theorem *is* provable in ZF and thus *shows* that PA (that is, "provably by induction") is strictly weaker is not only Robert's point but the whole point of Goodstein's theorem and the reason why I mentioned it and why IMHO it answers Hassan's question in the negative.

Comment: so, a property of the set N can be proven by induction if and only if it is in PA. And because Goodstein's theorem is a property of the set N and yet its proof is outside of PA. so no not all properties of N can be proven using induction, right?

Comment: @Hassan: Yes, this was the idea. Whether your first sentence is correct, is of course something which you have to decide: PA means that you really have nothing else than the inductive axiom at your hand to prove things.

Answer (score 2):

Any proof $P$ that proves that something is true for all numbers can trivially be converted into an inductive proof $P'$:

Base: Repeat proof P to conclude $\forall n \ P(n)$. Now plug in $0$ for $n$ to get $P(0)$

Step: Let $k$ be some arbitrary number and assume $P(k)$. Again, repeat proof P to conclude $\forall n \ P(n)$. Plug in $k+1$ for $n$ to get $P(k+1)$

This, of course, seems like a very cheeky answer ... and in some ways it is. But, I think there is a real question here as to what really counts as an inductive proof, i.e. to what extent the induction 'does the work'.

Comment: nice. but as you said I am interested in the extension of validity of the induction